# Kuberenets on CentOS 8 steam, is systemd-resolved.service required

Tags: centos, kubernetes

We have converted kubernets 1.19 cluster node OS from `CentOS 8` to `CentOS Steam 8` after upgrade node become `Ready` status, but PODs not starting on the node.

getting this message

`kubelet     open /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf: no such file or directory`

```
 kubelet[939]: E0628 11:38:45.492443     939 kuberuntime_sandbox.go:42] GeneratePodSandboxConfig for pod "kube-proxy-8rrl2_kube-system(09c30e9b-36a0-45b3-b64d-c052c0e27a9c)" failed: open /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf: no such file or directory
```

after starting `systemd-resolved.service` service pods are starting?

Is this service required on CentOS steam 8 for Kubernetes to run?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for Centos Steam 8 OS, I need to start the `systemd-reolved` service to make it work.

```
systemctl status systemd-resolved.service
systemctl enable systemd-resolved.service
```